# I want to repeat code but don't know how t use loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

js:

```
function change_color(color) {
$("body").animate({ backgroundColor:color }, '1000');
}

setTimeout(function () {
    change_color('#4AC900'
    );
}, 500);
setTimeout(function () {
    change_color('#964514'
    );
}, 1500);
setTimeout(function () {
    change_color('#EE0000'
    );
}, 1500);
setTimeout(function () {
    change_color('#FFE303'
    );
}, 1500);
setTimeout(function () {
    change_color('#8E388E'
    );
}, 1500);
setTimeout(function () {
    change_color('#FF00AA'
    );
}, 1500);
```

and I want to use it repeatedly but putting it in a while loop just crashes the site can anyone help?

Here is the site... its my little brothers site not mine... http://timothy.techbytbone.com/isaac.php

Comment: Please show us your while loop.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you explain the goal of this code? What is it not doing that you'd like it to do?

Comment: change the background color of the website in a non stop loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is all you need:

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WQt5q/)*

```
var c = 0;
var colors = ['#4AC900','#964514','#EE0000','#FFE303','#8E388E','#FF00AA'];
(function loop(){         
    $('body').stop().animate({backgroundColor : colors[c++%colors.length] }, 1000, loop);  
})();
```

(Prest attention that you need to use the jQuery UI to animate the CSS `background-color` property)

Comment: `c=++c%colors.length;` o_O You write code for people, not interpreter.

Comment: @zerkms you like it? (C'mon, mudulus are the first catch after the divisions in any JAVASCRIPT manual :) )

Comment: @zerkms Ok. You have my attention! You might be so **KIND** to explain. I'm really interested

Comment: so you really don't understand why I said that?

Comment: Thanks dude :) I like to use the most simple code I can and your's has the least code :)

Comment: @Tech by Tbone: less lines - doesn't mean easier to read and/or maintain

Comment: @zerksm.. now I understand you, but if you're saying this only cause the of modulus operator... that's like a child complaining cause it has to handle a dividend for the math class.

Comment: I know that i just like the least ammount of lines

Comment: @TechbyTbone I like it too... Don't know why zerkms don't like it. If you don't understand what the `%` modulo operator is ... Tech, I'll be really happy to explain it to you!. Vote vote and let's go!

Comment: its not working for me do i need to put it into an init function or something?

Comment: Just inside a document ready or: `(function($){  /*ALL YOUR CODE GOES HERE*/  })(jQuery);`

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan: `c=++c%colors.length` - this would confuse a lot because you need to keep in mind: 1) prefix unary operator nature 2) operators precedence

Comment: i added the website url in the main question go inspect the code see what im doing wron :S

Comment: @Tech by Tbone: but it is cool, isn't it? ;-) The less lines - the better ;-)

Comment: HAHAHAH @zerkms :) You enjoy it really :) I share your fun, but let's help this guy :)

Comment: @TechbyTbone on your page you still have your old code. Plese first replace it with mine.

Comment: @TechbyTbone Yes, you can wrap all your codes inside the `(function( $ ){ ...` not only mine. Look you are using an outdated jQuery library

Comment: @zerkms he was animating the whole `body` that's the only reason the 2 animations was conflicting. Fixed now. Cheers. ;P

Answer (score 3):

```
var colors = ['#4AC900', '#964514', '#EE0000', '#FFE303', '#8E388E', '#FF00AA'],
    len = colors.length,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    (function(i, color) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            change_color(color);
        }, (i + 1) * 500);
    })(i, colors[i]);
}
```

Comment: @myxospsm: I gave to OP an idea about how to do that, I didn't have aim to do all theirs work

Comment: it isnt looping... it just plays thru once

Comment: @Tech by Tbone: It wasn't clear from your initial question. Could you please rephrase it so it is obvious?

Comment: I want the background color to change constantly... exactly what Roko C. 's example does but his isn't working on my site

Comment: @Tech by Tbone: well - you liked it, why wouldn't you modify that code so it works? If you think that the less lines - the better to maintain - just perform an easy fix for it and be happy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var colors = {'#4AC900': 500,
              '#964514': 1500,
              // etc. Just continue with the color-millisecond combinations
             }

for(key in colors) {
 setTimeout(function () {
    change_color(key);
 }, colors[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is crashing because you can't set all the necessary timeouts at browser's loading. Here is a version of your code that should work.

```
var colors = ['#4AC900', '#964514', '#EE0000', '#FFE303', '#8E388E', '#FF00AA'];

var currentColorIndex = 0;
var scheduleChange;
scheduleChange = function() {
    change_color(currentColorIndex);
    currentColorIndex = (currentColorIndex + 1) % colors.length
    setTimeout(scheduleChange, 1000);
};

setTimeout(scheduleChange, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_color(color) {
  $("body").animate({ backgroundColor:color }, '1000');
}

setTimeout(function() {
  change_color('#4AC900')
}, 500);

colors = ['#964514', '#EE0000', '#FFE303', '#8E388E', '#FF00AA']

interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (! a.length) {
    return clearInterval(interval);
  }
  change_colors(a.shift());
}, 1500);
```

Have Fun. You should learn about [closures](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml) for not messing setIntervals. There are tons of libraries that animate colors and other stuff. I can recommend [morpheus by ded](https://github.com/ded/morpheus).